# Dynamic load into treeview from database - populating grandchilds

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I need to populate a treeview from database data to look like:

```
A
- abc 1
- def 2
        - fed 1
        - cbd 2 
B
- ghi 1
        - ihjg 1
```

There are three tables. One that consists of - let's say 'Grandparent' - data, a second for 'Parent' data and a third for 'Grandchild' data

For now I've managed to load data for 'Grandparents' and 'Parents':

```
private void PopulateTreeView()
{
    try
    {
        DataTable dtProjekti = objDB.dbGetTable("SELECT * FROM tblProjekti");
        DataTable dtAktivnosti = objDB.dbGetTable("SELECT * FROM tblAktivnosti");
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.Tables.Add(dtProjekti);
        ds.Tables.Add(dtAktivnosti);
        ds.Relations.Add("childrens", dtProjekti.Columns["OznakaProjekta"], dtAktivnosti.Columns["OznakaProjekta"]);

        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            treeProjekti.Nodes.Clear();

            foreach (DataRow masterRow in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                TreeNode masterNode = new TreeNode(masterRow["OznakaProjekta"].ToString(), 0, 1);
                treeProjekti.Nodes.Add(masterNode);

                foreach (DataRow childRow in masterRow.GetChildRows("childrens"))
                {
                    TreeNode childNode = new TreeNode(childRow["NazivAktivnosti"].ToString());                          
                    masterNode.Nodes.Add(childRow["IdAkt"].ToString(), childRow["NazivAktivnosti"].ToString(), 0, 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("Unable to populate treeview" + ex.Message);
    }
```

But I don't understand how to add Grandchildren from third table to Parents.
Parent and Grandchild are linked with the table field ID in a 1:N relationship.

Comment: I really don't believe there is enough information here to fully answer this question - I only see two tables. I think you could just add another DataTable (e.g. DataTable dtGrandchildren) and create a relationship between this and dtAktivnosti and nest another foreach loop and add the grandchildren to the childNode.

Comment: I have tried to add another table and make relation but gives me an error. It seems that is not possible to put three tables in one dataset.